# PHP sending selected variables in a email to user

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, email

I would like to send the selected objects to a email address.

here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/62g3s8sz/

I know a email can be send with PHP and i have tried many ways but all unsuccessful.

The email needs to correspond with the items selected.

So if Cooler Master K-380 is selected with AMD FM2 A6-6400K Dual Core 3,9GHz i need it to list these items

Case     : Cooler Master K-380                : price
Processor: AMD FM2 A6-6400K Dual Core 3,9GHz  : price

And then send it to the email address that the person is logged in with.
i know that $loggedInUser->email will display the email address.

If anyone knows how to send all this information within a email to the logged in person that would be great.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/formcalc.js"></script>

<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form.php" id="computerform">
    <div>
        <div class="cont_order">
            <fieldset>
                <legend></legend>
                <label>Case</label>
                <br>
                <label class='radiolabel'>
                    <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="selectedcase" value="2001" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Cooler Master K-350 - ($10)</label>
                <br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'>
                    <input type="radio" name="selectedcase" value="2002" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Cooler Master K-380 - ($20)</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <label>Processor</label>
                <br>
                <label class='radiolabel'>
                    <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="selectedprocessor" value="3001" onclick="calculateTotal()" />AMD FM2 A4-5300 Dual Core 3,4GHz - ($10)</label>
                <br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'>
                    <input type="radio" name="selectedprocessor" value="3002" onclick="calculateTotal()" />AMD FM2 A6-6400K Dual Core 3,9GHz - ($20)</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <label>Totale price</label>
                <div class="total">
                    <div id="case"></div>
                    <div id="totalPrice"></div>
                </div>
                <br>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Bestel' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript code

```
 var case_prices = new Array();
 case_prices["2001"]=10;
 case_prices["2002"]=20;

 var processor_prices = new Array();
 processor_prices["3001"]=10;
 processor_prices["3002"]=20;




window.onload = function() 
{
    calculateTotal();
}

// getCasePrice() finds the price based on the selected case
// Here, we need to take user's the selection from radio button selection
function getCasePrice()
{  
    var casePrice=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="computerform"
    var theForm = document.forms["computerform"];
    //Get a reference to the case the user Chooses name=selectedcase":
    var selectedCase = theForm.elements["selectedcase"];
    //We loop through each radio buttons
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedCase.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedCase[i].checked)
        {
            //we set cakeSizePrice to the value of the selected radio button
            //i.e. if the user choose the 8" cake we set it to 25
            //by using the cake_prices array
            //We get the selected Items value
            //For example cake_prices["Round8".value]"
            casePrice = case_prices[selectedCase[i].value];
            //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
            //No reason to continue if we get a match
            break;
        }
    }
    //We return the cakeSizePrice
    return casePrice;
}


// getCasePrice() finds the price based on the selected case
// Here, we need to take user's the selection from radio button selection
function getProcessorPrice()
{  
    var processorPrice=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="computerform"
    var theForm = document.forms["computerform"];
    //Get a reference to the cake the user Chooses name=selectedprocessor":
    var selectedProcessor = theForm.elements["selectedprocessor"];
    //We loop through each radio buttons
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedProcessor.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedProcessor[i].checked)
        {
            //we set cakeSizePrice to the value of the selected radio button
            //i.e. if the user choose the 8" cake we set it to 25
            //by using the cake_prices array
            //We get the selected Items value
            //For example cake_prices["Round8".value]"
            processorPrice = processor_prices[selectedProcessor[i].value];
            //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
            //No reason to continue if we get a match
            break;
        }
    }
    //We return the cakeSizePrice
    return processorPrice;
}


function calculateTotal()
{
    //Here we get the total price by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var computerPrice = getCasePrice() + getProcessorPrice() + getCoolerPrice() + getMotherboardPrice();

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Totale prijs: &euro;"+computerPrice ;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Please include the relevant contents of `contact-form.php` and let us know specifically what goes wrong.

Comment: I can not add this because there is non. But that is not the problem i need to know how to make those variables work inside the contact-form.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't like just pasting a link to the answer but ...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

So all you need is something like this

```
$content = "..write it here yadda yadda whatever is your mail content ..";
$ok = mail($mailTo,"Hello, this is the mail subject",$content);
```

Note this will send plain mail, there are a few extra steps to make HTML mail, all covered on the link above. Good luck

Few reminders: it will probably not work on your local machine unless you have a mail daemon installed and working with PHP, and also you might need to tweak the last parameters on that mail() function depending on how PHP is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code must be in **contact-form.php**, or you must change that name in the HTML.
Use the `mail()` function of PHP.

In PHP, the form data is available in the superglobal variable `$_REQUEST`.
Try `print_r($_REQUEST);` to see what is in there.

Answer (score 0):

In php, you send mails through the `mail()` function (or you could use an external mailer plugin), which requires a few basic concepts. Example:

```
    $to = "email-from-user@some-email-client.com";
    $subject = "You just made an order";
    $body = $message;
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: noreply@somewebsite.com";

    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        echo "1";
    }
```

Quickly explained, you need a few parameters for the function to work. I just moved over some items from my own mail function, but i ll explain. You need a target (the `$to` variable) a subject (the `$subject` variable and the content, which i defined here as `$body` ... now i added headers too, which is additional, but for you, it might be important. The first two lines allows you to use HTML in the email, which you can use to markup your mail, such as using tables. Also you can specify where the email came from.

I use an echo there to check if it got through the mail function, if so, i use that parameter in an ajax call return to put up an appending div.

Remember, calling an external stylesheet isnt working in this so preferly, you have to do inline styling on your elements.

**edit**

I see you re trying to get the totals from your fieldset up in the email. Since you use a div to show the end content, sending a form will not allow you to transfer the variable from the total. (btw, if you submit this form, you actually go with 3002 and 2001 for example as variables, instead of the names in the email, thus you got to do some query work to push out the right names) Since I asume these prices are also in a database, you can calculate from there on the price as fixed and push it out in a query as well, which you then have to use in the `$body` variable.

Trying to point you in the right direction